# How to make chatbot using NLP like Dialogflow?

Tags: chat-bots, natural-language-processing

I want to apply the concept that exists in the [Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/) API in my e-commerce website.

I get some references in this regard :

1. Tokenization
2. Part Of Speech
3. Named Entity Recognition
4. Rule based

I just saw that I just didn't understand how to implement it on the website. 
so I still don't know how the truth is.

please give me a method or explanation that can help me create a chatbot for ecommerce that can give action when a user asks for a product and wants to place an order or something else.

Please give me some explanation or method or references :(

Answer (score 1):

You are right that you will have to implement the above steps before building any chat bot, this is because your computer doesn't understand text like you and I do. Therefore, text has to be pre-processed(converted) into a format that the computer can work with Tokenization, Parts of Speech Tagging and Named Entity Recognition are such pre-processing techniques.

Rule based means when you create rules for deciding how should your chat bot behave in a given situation.

You can have a look at this blog which teaches how to deploy a chat bot using DialogFlow on Slack - https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/03/how-to-build-an-intelligent-chatbot-for-slack-using-dialogflow-api/